# Good use of breakpoints in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode6, breakpoints

Does anyone have a very specific use for Xcode breakpoints that they wanted to share? I am learning through         http://www.swifteducation.github.io

The breakpoint isn't used to its full potential I believe and I wanted to have some creative feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little-known use for breakpoints is to use them as bookmarks for your code. I use them to quickly navigate to pieces of my code that I revisit a lot. 
Just create a breakpoint as you would normally (click the gutter to the left of a line of code) and then disable it by right-clicking on it and selecting "Disable Breakpoint". You can display all the breakpoints by bringing up the Breakpoint Navigator with this hotkey:

⌘7 : Breakpoint Navigator

or just click on the breakpoint icon in the navigation bar on the left-hand side
[screenshot here](http://corsarus.com/img/028_DebuggingBreakpoints/breakpointNavigator.png)

Clicking on the breakpoint in the navigator will instantly take you to that line of code just like a bookmark.

Just remember to make sure they are disabled and light blue in colour otherwise they will cause your program to halt at that breakpoint.